# How to eliminate the quotation marks of a list of strings?

Tags: erlang

I receive the following list of strings from a text file:

["{0988070979,APP03@media}","{0988070978,APP01@media}","{0988070977,APP02@media}"]

**I need the same list but without the quotation marks ( " " )**, something like this:

[{0988070979,APP03@media},{0988070978,APP01@media},{0988070977,APP02@media}]

Comment: It looks like all of the commas are still there.

Comment: Sorry my bad english, I use a wrong expression when i said comma i mean quotation marks. I edit the post

Comment: How you want to define APP03@media? It is better to write what you want to do as a result

Comment: Please give some more details. What is exactly in the text file? How do you currently read (show your code)? What are you trying to achieve? Is it a list of atoms? A list of tuples?

Comment: Is `0988070979` a number or an atom? Because if the former then it would be `988070979` (without the leading zero), and if the later it would be `'0988070979'` (with apostrophes since in atom can't start with a number unquoted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1> L = ["{0988070979,APP03@media}","{0988070978,APP01@media}","{0988070977,APP02@media}"].
["{0988070979,APP03@media}","{0988070978,APP01@media}",
 "{0988070977,APP02@media}"]
2> [{N, M} || X <- L, [N, M] <- [string:tokens(X, "{},")]].                               
[{"0988070979","APP03@media"},
 {"0988070978","APP01@media"},
 {"0988070977","APP02@media"}]
```

or (not recommended)

```
3> [{list_to_integer(N), list_to_atom(M)} || X <- L, [N, M] <- [string:tokens(X, "{},")]].                                                                    
[{988070979,'APP03@media'},
 {988070978,'APP01@media'},
 {988070977,'APP02@media'}]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [erl_scan](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_scan.html) module to `tokenize` the string and [erl_parse](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_parse.html) to convert the tokens to a erlang term.

let your strings be `Str`

```
{ok, Ts, _} = erl_scan:string(Str).
{ok, Tup} = erl_parse:parse_term(Ts).
```

The `Tup` is the Tuples you need ...